# 'GenericADOException: could not execute query' when trying to run Orchard CMS for the first time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, orchardcms-1.9

I opened Orchard CMS 1.9.2 (solution) in Visual Studio 2017 (Community version), compiled it, set the "Orchard.Web" as a Startup Project in the Properties of the solution and then pressed F5 to start debugging in Firefox 58.0.1 (64-bit). The browser gave me HTTP 404 Error and in Orchard's log I've found this (written three times):

> ... Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null)
>   
> - A tenant could not be started: Default
>   
> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
>   
> [ select shelldescr0_.Id as Id7_, shelldescr0_.SerialNumber
>   
> as SerialNu2_7_ from dbo_Settings_ShellDescriptorRecord shelldescr0_ where > shelldescr0_.Id is not null ]
>   
> [SQL: select shelldescr0_.Id as Id7_, shelldescr0_.SerialNumber
>   
> as SerialNu2_7_ from dbo_Settings_ShellDescriptorRecord shelldescr0_ where > shelldescr0_.Id is not null] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:      > 
> Invalid object name 'dbo_Settings_ShellDescriptorRecord'.
>   
> in Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.                                 > 
> b__31_1(ShellSettings settings) in D:\...

How to run it successfully to get to the first page where I setup the database connection etc.?

Comment: Check your connection string is correct and the user has the proper permissions to run the scripts

Comment: The connection string should be set during the initial setup, that I am unsuccessfully trying to run. I also tried to add proper connection string from another project (modified to suit my database and my credentials) before I try to run the initial setup, but it didn't help.